# How to get -flto to work?

Tags: gcc

I'm using GCC 4.7.2 and LD 2.23 but when I add -flto to my compile options my compile time increases by over 20%! The manual seems to indicate that -fuse-linker-plugin is needed for the optimization to work. It also says that it's enabled by default with -flto but when I add it explicitly I see the following error in the link command:

```
g++: error: -fuse-linker-plugin is not supported in this configuration
```

According to manual, it should be supported by LD 2.21 or greater. Any idea why I'm getting this error? For reference here are examples of my full compile commands:

```
g++ -Wall -pipe -O3 -flto -fno-strict-aliasing -mtune=generic --no-exceptions -fPIC -c some.cc
g++ -o exec -Xlinker some1.o some2.o -static some1.a some2.a -Wl,--wrap,open -flto -fuse-linker-plugin
```

Running 'ld --help | grep plugin' shows "-plugin" option so I don't understand why GCC is complaining:

```
-plugin PLUGIN              Load named plugin
-plugin-opt ARG             Send arg to last-loaded plugin
```

Comment: Have you checked [this thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-04/msg00220.html)?

Comment: thanks for the link. I didn't build our GCC but I ran GCC with strace and don't even see any calls to LD so I don't think GCC is throwing an error from it.

Comment: removing that option and using strace I can confirm that system LD is not being used. The version used is 2.23.1. Not sure if it's GOLD or not.

Comment: You say this is a custom build?

Comment: There are not special options required. Just use g++ to link, use -flto also with link step (and possibly also compilation switches). AFAIK that plug-in was required in 4.5 or before that.

Comment: Just to emphasise what the (not accepted) answer says, the purpose of `-flto` is not to reduce build time; it's to optimise the compiled binary for runtime performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link time optimizations aren't supposed to reduce compilation time, but optimize runtime of your program.

@options, just add "-flto -fuse-linker-plugin" to your CFLAGS(or CXXFLAGS for c++) and LDFLAGS and it should work just fine.

@gold: ld --version is probably gonna return gnu LD, to switch to gold, make ld symlink

```
 which ld
```

point to

```
 which ld.gold
```

e.g.

```
 ln -s /usr/bin/ld.gold /usr/bin/ld
```